# convert .tif to .tiff for pdf conversion

Tags: python, pdf, type-conversion, format, tiff

I am trying norm my document data input and I am facing a lot of .pdf, .tiff, and .tiff documents.

I want to normalise all documents by getting them into .pdf format but facing issues with the .tif documents in my to pdf conversion function.

The problem is dealing with

```
def tiff_to_pdf(tiff_path: str) -> str:
    if tiff_path.endswith(".tif"):
        tiff_path.replace(".tif", ".tiff")
    pdf_path = tiff_path.replace('.tiff', '.pdf')
    if not os.path.exists(tiff_path): raise Exception(f'{tiff_path} does not find.')
    image = Image.open(tiff_path)

    images = []
    for i, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(image)):
        page = page.convert("RGB")
        images.append(page)
    if len(images) == 1:
        images[0].save(pdf_path)
    else:
        images[0].save(pdf_path, save_all=True, append_images=images[1:])
    return pdf_path
```

Also simply trying to load the .tif as in the snippet below causes an error:

```
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a_image.tif'
```

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('a_image.tif')
im.show()
```

I honestly checked the directory and it is finding every .tiff file and is able to get a pdf out of it, but not working with .tif files.

Any help would be highly appreciated and intermediate steps to get from .tif to .pdf are of course fine.

Comment: did you tried using absolute path?

Comment: `.tif` and `.tiff` is the same format so you can only rename it wothout using `Pillow`. But to rename you have to use `os.rename(old_name, new_name)`. And if you want to convert it to .pdf then use original name `.tif` to load images and save in `.pdf`

Comment: you have to assign new name to variable `tiff_path = tiff_path.replace(".tif", ".tiff")` but it would change path which you need to open file - better use if/else with `pdf_path = tiff_path.replace('.tif', '.pdf')` and `pdf_path = tiff_path.replace('.tiff', '.pdf')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change in string `.tif` to `.tiff` but you don't assign new string to variable.

But you should change `.tif` directly to `.pdf`

```
if tiff_path.endswith(".tif"):
    pdf_path = tiff_path.replace(".tif", ".pdf")
elif tiff_path.endswith(".tiff"):
    pdf_path = tiff_path.replace('.tiff', '.pdf')
else:    
    print('Wrong extension:', tiff_path)
    return   # exit function with `None` when extension is wrong
    # or raise error
    # raise Exception(f'{tiff_path} has wrong extension.')

# ... code which converts image to PDF ...

image = Image.open(tiff_path)

# ...

    images[0].save(pdf_path)

# ...

    images[0].save(pdf_path, save_all=True, , append_images=images[1:])
```

---

And when you check file then you may need to use full path

```
im = Image.open('/full/path/to/a_image.tif')
```

because code may run in different folder and it may not find this file in different folder.

Comment: Simply changing the file extension from `.tif` (or `.tiff`) to `.pdf` will **not** convert the file to `.pdf` *format*.

Comment: @martineau at first moment I wrote the same comment :) but later I realized that it uses these strings to load image `Image.open(tiff_path)` and later save it in PDF `.save(pdf_path)` - and `Pillow` should convert it.

Comment: There's no need to do that, so I think it would have been appropriate for you to have at least mentioned it's not — because if nothing else it's also confusing (obviously).